# How do I prove that $span(v, w) = span(v, v + w)$ where $v$ and $w$ are vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that I have to set $x=c_1v + c_2w$, but have no idea what to do afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

$x$ is any vector in the span of $(v,w)$.
Try to find $d_1$ and $d_2$ so that $x=d_1v+d_2(v+w)$  That will show $x$ is in the span of $(v,v+w)$, and therefore $span(v,w)$ is a subset of $span(v,v+w)$.
Then let $y$ be any vector in $span(v,v+w)$, so $y=a_1v+a_2(v+w)$, and try to show it is in $span(v,w)$.